# How can I get the width of an element using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I realise I can use jQuery to get the width of an element, but I'm curious; is there a way to do so using AngularJS?

Comment: is css gives the right value for box-resizing situations or with auto calculated widths?

Comment: try  `$('element').width();` in js.. replace `element` with use of your ID or class. Reference : http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: @MoorthyGK there is no Sizzle library (for selectors) nor there is no width plugin in jQLite. Pls read the question before answering.

Comment: `css` returns the computed width, but as a string with `px` at the end AFAIK, just like in jQuery.

Comment: Or you can use `getBoundingClientRect`. It will give you a width as well as other useful numbers.

Comment: @dfsq what about compat?

Comment: All main browsers, IE4+.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Native JS (#id):

```
document.getElementById(id).clientWidth;
```

Native JS (querySelector (class, id, css3 selector)):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class")[0].clientWidth;
```

Plugging this into angular.element:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById(id)).clientWidth;
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".class")[0]).clientWidth;
```

If you need to get non rounded numbers, use getBoundingClientRect.

```
angular.element(document.getElementById(id)).getBoundingClientRect();
```

Some resources on the subject:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781509(VS.85).aspx
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientWidth
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect

If this floats your boat in terms of syntax and the no-need to plug jQuery into the mix, be wary of cross browser hell.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the `angular.element` examples don't work for me. I think you need to *unwrap* the DOM element from its jqLite wrapper in order to access basic DOM methods/properties. i.e. `angular.element(document.getElementById(id))[0].clientWidth;`, NOT `angular.element(document.getElementById(id)).clientWidth;` This of course makes the whole `angular.element` thing in this example silly, but it is necessary to do something like this to get at the vanilla dom element from, say, a `link` functions `element`.

Comment: @ZachLysobey is right...at least in Chrome, you need to select the first element: angular.element(document.getElementById(id))[0].clientWidth

Answer (score 11):

If you've been scratching your head like me over all these suggestions and they don't work, i found i had to set a timeout.  I'm not sure why, maybe because i'm using material design attributes on my divs.

```
setTimeout(function(){
     var divsize = angular.element(document.getElementById('fun_div')).prop('offsetWidth');   
     console.log('Width of fun_div: ' + divsize);
    },50);
```

Comment: Using setTimeout for this purpose is not a good idea. In this case you assume the browser will have finished rendering everything you need within 50ms. I'm sure a modern PC can handle that, but what about a budget smartphone? Use Angulars $timeout instead, it guarantees all rendering has finished, before calling your function.

Comment: @HammerNL I agree.