# get element width with angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to get an element's width in my ionic app. But I get an `undefined` with this code:

html:

```
$scope.suggestProWidth = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("suggestPro")[0]).clientWidth;
console.log("$scope.suggestProWidth", $scope.suggestProWidth);
```

controllers.js:

```
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="s in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in prodata | matchingProBrand:computed.proName:computed.proBrand | limitTo:s*sliderItemNumber+sliderItemNumber  | limitTo:-sliderItemNumber">
                    <a class="suggestPro" ng-click="launchComputeService(item.id)">
                        <span><img ng-src={{imagesUrls[item.imageName]}} /></span>
                        <p class="flex-caption"> {{item.model}} - {{item.name}}</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </ion-slide>
```

Can you help me figure this out ?

Thanks

Comment: What is `suggestPro`? `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` takes `.class` or `#id` or `tagName` or any css selector.

Comment: suggestPro is a class. Should I put the dot ?

Comment: This `$scope.suggestProWidth = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".suggestPro")[0]).clientWidth;
  console.log("$scope.suggestProWidth", $scope.suggestProWidth);` doesn't work either...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the width of an element using AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544137/how-can-i-get-the-width-of-an-element-using-angularjs)

Comment: @isherwood this is exactly what I did but doesn't work

Comment: A plunker or some HTML code would help

Answer (score 2):

Initially, create an attribute directive to get width of an element and assign to the `<a></a>` tag. In the custom directive, you can get width of an element easily.

HTML:

```
<ion-slide ng-repeat="s in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in prodata |  
      matchingProBrand:computed.proName:computed.proBrand | 
      limitTo:s*sliderItemNumber+sliderItemNumber | limitTo: 
      sliderItemNumber">
        <a custom-item class="suggestPro" 
          ng-click="launchComputeService(item.id)">
          <span><img ng-src={{imagesUrls[item.imageName]}} /></span>
          <p class="flex-caption"> {{item.model}} - {{item.name}}</p>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>   
</ion-slide>
```

JS:

```
angular.module(modulename)
 .directive('customItem',function(){
   return{
     restrict : 'A',
     link:function(scope,element){
        var eleWidth = element.innerWidth();
        console.log(eleWidth);
     }
   }
 });
```

Accessing element to get its width in controller is not a good practice. So, best way to get its width is using custom directive.

Comment: thanks, your solution seems "good practices" so I like it of course. But how can I then use the width to calculate something else in the controller (the number of item displayed in a slider (slide-box from ionic) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it with angular, here is the code;

```
angular.element(document.getElementById(id)).clientWidth;
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".class")[0]).clientWidth;
```

but I will sugest you put an id for that div, and use the first one. like this:

```
<li id="suggestion" ng-repeat="item in prodata | matchingProBrand:computed.proName:computed.proBrand | limitTo:s*sliderItemNumber+sliderItemNumber  | limitTo:-sliderItemNumber">
                <a class="suggestPro" ng-click="launchComputeService(item.id)">
                    <span><img ng-src={{imagesUrls[item.imageName]}} /></span>
                    <p class="flex-caption"> {{item.model}} - {{item.name}}</p>
                </a>
```

and angular element:`angular.element(document.getElementById(#suggestion)).clintWidth;`

let me if it works with you bro.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's `clientWidth` property does not work on HTML elements that have a `display` type of `inline`. By default an `anchor` tag is `inline`.

You can try adding `display:inline-block` as a style to the element.

```
<a ng-click="" style="display:inline-block" />
```

Be aware `clientWidth` does not include any border or scrollbar, where as `offsetWidth` does.

In your example, you have your script before the HTML you are trying to find. This will not work unless you run that particular block after page load. As a simple solution you can move the script block below the HTML.